# SimpleDateFormatter Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a string date Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:39:56 +0000 which i want to convert to the date format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Below are the lines of code i am trying to achieve it. But it is returning unparseable date exception

```
String date_s = "Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:39:56 +0000";
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dt.parse(date_s);  
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Any advice?

Comment: Look at the `SimpleDateFormat` you're trying to use to parse the value. It doesn't have the same format as the value you're trying to parse. It's not clear why your second `SimpleDateFormat` has a pattern of `MMM d, yyyy` as that doesn't seem to be either the input format or the desired output format...

Comment: the question is as common as "`if (str1 == str2)` behaves incorrectly"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8, you can do it in one line with the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:39:56 +0000", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Answer (score 4):

'Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:39:56 +0000' is not in the right format for `yyyy-MM-dd` to parse it

If you want it to work, try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = in.parse("Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:01:01 +0000");
String outdate = out.format(date);
System.out.println(outdate);
```

---

### [Ideone](http://ideone.com/CrLdqG)